# Command failed with exit code 2 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, visual-studio-2015

When deployed on riple nexus tablet it is done well,but when i am trying to deployed on device it will throw error:-
Command failed with exit code 2

I am new at cross platform cordova  app my html javascripts works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error - with exit code 2. Try to use answers from this page.
Exactly first point: Security Vs. innerHTML
https://www.hoessl.eu/2014/12/on-using-the-ionic-framework-for-windows-phone-8-1-apps/
I hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you have to go to **Tools** menu. Then **Options > Tools for Apache Cordova**. There's a tool named Dependency Checker. You usually need *Android SDK* as well as *JDK (Java Development Kit)*.